# College question about using Jquery to perform unit test and evaluation using qunit

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I am quite new to JS and have been given a college project where I need to use jQuery to simulate user interactions on a webform and then use qunit to validate this.

As it stands, I am attempting to set the html form fields as below using ids.

```
function scenario1() {

     $("#price").val(1000); //sets price of textbox
    $("#passengernum").val(1); //sets price of textbox
    $("#myButton").click(); // clicks update button which updates a "Final price" field.
    return $("#finalprice").val; // returns "Final Price" field value
}
```

Then in the Html, I am trying to integrate this into the qunit testing as below:

```
QUnit.module("ALAC Tests");

    QUnit.test("", function( assert ) 
        {
    assert.equal( scenario1(),700,"TC8");
        }
    );
```

Unfortunately this causes errors on the qunit section of the html page when ran (I have this in the body).

Am I performing this test correctly or should this be done another way. The professor that has requested this assignment only gave notes on extremely basic jQuery usage.

Sorry in advance if this is a stupid question, I am very new to development.

Thanks all.

Comment: `val` is a function, so first off, in `scenario1`, try doing `return $("#finalprice").val()` which should retrieve the value. As it stands, what you're returning is the function definition itself.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad that was it! Added as an answer for others to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment above, looks like you were trying to use `val` as a property, but it's a function. In `scenario1`, try doing return `$("#finalprice").val()` which should retrieve the value. As it stands, what you're returning is the function definition itself.